# Handling logins

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-accounts

I've started a project to build a small and simple web application in HTML5/Canvas/JS that allows users to graph simple sets of data.

I want to implement and user account/login system but I want to use JS to do this rather than traditional PHP solutions.

I've been following this guide as an example. http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/building-a-login-system-in-node-js-and-mongodb/

My question is, after implementing a system like this, how does one treat/handle/deal with a user being either logged in or out in my code all the time? What are common and best practice appraoches for doing this?

Comment: In ExpressJS you can pass more than one handler into a route. Each handler is then used in a chain allowing you to do whatever you want. A typical approach to shield certain routes with a login is to simply add a login handler to those routes and have it deal with authentication, tracking, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a middleware function such as:

```
function needUser(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
        return;
    }
    next();
}
```

Any routes that are publicly available to not-logged-in users can just ignore this and be set up as normal. Any routes that require a logged-in user can include this as a middleware.

```
app.get('/inbox', needUser, inboxRoute);
```